# Keep on changing background colour without reloading page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm facing a problem while changing the background colour using js.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>First Js</title>
</head>
<body onload="init();">

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {
        var color = '#'+(0x1000000+(Math.random())*0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1,6);
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
</script>
</html>
```

The problem I'm facing is that, everytime I need to change the background color I need to reload it. Is there any way by which it automatically keeps on changing itself.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way by which it automatically keeps on changing itself.

You can call `init` method using `setTimeout` by the end of `init` method itself

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {
        var color = '#'+(0x1000000+(Math.random())*0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1,6);
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
        setTimeout( init, 5000 );  //once done, call it back again after 5 sec
    }
    init(); //call this once
</script>
```

No need to call it in `body onload` now.

**Demo**

```js
function init() {
  var color = '#' + (0x1000000 + (Math.random()) * 0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1, 6);
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
  setTimeout(init, 5000);
}
init();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>First Js</title>
</head>
<body onload="init();">

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {
        var color = '#'+(0x1000000+(Math.random())*0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1,6);
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
    setInterval(function(){
      init();
    },1000);
</script>
</html>
```